# Why is the value of function j not decrementing?

Tags: c, xcode, computer-science

I've been trying to get an output as --

```
*****

****

***

**

*
```

in separate lines, but instead Xcode is showing 5 stars in every line. How to get a decremented value of function j ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=5;j>=1;j--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code, not a screen shot (it's actually easier).

Comment: int main(); { int i,j; for(i=1;i<=5;i++) { for(j=5;j>=1;j--) { printf("*");} printf("\n"); } return 0; }

Comment: No, edit your question.  That is no more readable.

Comment: There is no function `j` in your code. And how would a function be decremented anyway? You mean the **variable** `j`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(j = 5;j >= 1; j--)
```

to

```
for(j = 5;j >= i; j--)
```

See the [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.org/DNKPTv4N)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
for(j = (5-i+1);j >= 1;j--)
```

Comment: This wrong. It will print the patter upside-down.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in setting the nested for loop. The counter j should start from 5-i+1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit counter-intuitive; you should have the outer loop holding the number of stars you want on that line and the inner loop holding the current star count:

```
for (int stars = 5; stars > 0; stars--) {
    for (int count = 0; count < stars; count++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

(`> 0` is generally used instead of `>= 1`).